# neural network produces similar pattern for all inputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am attempting to train an ANN on time series data in Keras. I have three vectors of data that are broken into scrolling window sequences (i.e. for vector l).

```
np.array([l[i:i+window_size] for i in range( len(l) - window_size)])
```

The target vector is similarly windowed so the neural net output is a prediction of the target vector for the next window_size number of time steps. All the data is normalized with a min-max scaler. It is fed into the neural network as a shape=(nb_samples, window_size, 3). Here is a plot of the 3 input vectors.

[image: input vector plots]

The only output I've managed to muster from the ANN is the following plot. Target vector in blue, predictions in red (plot is zoomed in to make the prediction pattern legible). Prediction vectors are plotted at window_size intervals so each one of the repeated patterns is one prediction from the net.
[image]

I've tried many different model architectures, number of epochs, activation functions, short and fat networks, skinny, tall. This is my current one (it's a little out there).

```
Conv1D(64,4, input_shape=(None,3)) ->
Conv1d(32,4) -> 
Dropout(24) -> 
LSTM(32) ->
Dense(window_size)
```

But nothing I try will affect the neural net from outputting this repeated pattern. I must be misunderstanding something about time-series or LSTMs in Keras. But I'm very lost at this point so any help is greatly appreciated. I've attached the full code at this repository.

https://github.com/jaybutera/dat-toy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with your code a little and I think I have a few suggestions for getting you on the right track. The code doesn't seem to match your graphs exactly, but I assume you've tweaked it a bit since then. Anyway, there are two main problems:

1. The biggest problem is in your data preparation step. You basically have the data shapes backwards, in that you have a single timestep of input for X and a timeseries for Y. Your input shape is (18830, 1, 8), when what you really want is (18830, 30, 8) so that the full 30 timesteps are fed into the LSTM. Otherwise the LSTM is only operating on one timestep and isn't really useful. To fix this, I changed the line in `common.py` from

   `X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])`

   to

   `X = windowfy(X, winsize)`

   Similarly, the output data should probably be only 1 value, from what I've gathered of your goals from the plotting function. There are certainly some situations where you want to predict a whole timeseries, but I don't know if that's what you want in this case. I changed `Y_train` to use `fuels` instead of `fuels_w` so that it only had to predict one step of the timeseries.
2. Training for 100 epochs might be way too much for this simple network architecture. In some cases when I ran it, it looked like there was some overfitting going on. Observing the decrease of loss in the network, it seems like maybe only 3-4 epochs are needed.

Here is the graph of predictions after 3 training epochs with the adjustments I mentioned. It's not a great prediction, but it looks like it's on the right track now at least. Good luck to you!
[image: Predictions after three epochs]

**EDIT: Example predicting multiple output timesteps:**

```
from sklearn import datasets, preprocessing
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from keras import models, layers

INPUT_WINDOW = 10
OUTPUT_WINDOW = 5  # Predict 5 steps of the output variable.
# Randomly generate some regression data (not true sequential data; samples are independent).
np.random.seed(11798)
X, y = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=4, noise=.1)
# Rescale 0-1 and convert into windowed sequences.
X = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X)
y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1))
X = np.array([X[i:i + INPUT_WINDOW] for i in range(len(X) - INPUT_WINDOW)])
y = np.array([y[i:i + OUTPUT_WINDOW] for i in range(INPUT_WINDOW - OUTPUT_WINDOW,
                                                    len(y) - OUTPUT_WINDOW)])
print(np.shape(X))  # (990, 10, 4) - Ten timesteps of four features
print(np.shape(y))  # (990, 5, 1)  - Five timesteps of one features

# Construct a simple model predicting output sequences.
m = models.Sequential()
m.add(layers.LSTM(20, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(INPUT_WINDOW, 4)))
m.add(layers.LSTM(20, activation='relu'))
m.add(layers.RepeatVector(OUTPUT_WINDOW))
m.add(layers.LSTM(20, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
m.add(layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
print(m.summary())

m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
m.fit(X[:800], y[:800], batch_size=10, epochs=60)  # Train on first 800 sequences.
preds = m.predict(X[800:], batch_size=10)  # Predict the remaining sequences.
print('Prediction:\n' + str(preds[0]))
print('Actual:\n' + str(y[800]))
# Correlation should be around r = .98, essentially perfect.
print('Correlation: ' + str(stats.pearsonr(y[800:].flatten(), preds.flatten())[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been editing the code since I posed the question, that was a mistake. The thing is I do want to predict more than one time step into the future. At the time I asked the question, the input shape was (18830, 30, 8) as you described, but the outputs were nonsense. Is there another way to predict more than one time step into the future?

Comment: @jay I am not super familiar with sequence prediction, but I added a simple example that tries to predict some short sequences. The randomly generated data are not true sequences, so there isn't a pattern that can be learned and so the output doesn't mean a lot, but you can see some results.

Comment: @jay Actually, I improved the example a little and it does learn something now though the data is still not truly sequential and so the first 5 input timesteps are probably not actually helping the model learn anything about the last 5 output timesteps. Also not that if your input and output sequences are the same length you don't need the `RepeatVector` business, and can just stick with sequences the whole way through the model.

Comment: Nice this looks good. Can you explain why you made the architecture you did? What does timedistributed do and why did you enable return sequences to it?

Comment: @jay Returning sequences from the LSTM allows you to get (?, 5, 20) shaped outputs instead of (?, 20), preserving the separate predictions for each sequence. Then the `TimeDistributed` wrapper applies a layer (`Dense` in this case) to each sequence so that you can get outputs for each sequence individually. Thus you maintain the three-dimensional (batch_size, sequence_length, num_features) shape that you want to output, instead of collapsing down to (batch_size, num_features).